# Can't paste(yank) selected region by multiple-cursor

Tags: multiple-cursors

Is it possible to copy/paste region.

I whant to copy city's name from the next text.

Here text:

```
000 111 222 key=Paris, 555 666
111 222 key=Berlin, 555 666
1111111110 111 key=Toronto, 555 666
222222222 111 222 key=London, 555 666
```

To do this I use Multiple cursors:  https://github.com/magnars/multiple-cursors.el

here steps:

1. Select `key`
   [image]
2. `M-x mark-all-like-this`
   [image]
   M-x mark-all-line-like-this
3. `C-M-SPC`

[image]

4. Copy selected region to kill ring by `M-w`
5. Move cursor after text and paste (yank) by `C-y`

And here result:
[image]

As you can see it paste (yank) only first word (Paris). Why it not paste all other selected word (`Berlin`, ...) ?

Answer (score 2):

It's in the [README](https://github.com/magnars/multiple-cursors.el/blob/master/README.md#tips-and-tricks):

> If you get out of multiple-cursors-mode and yank it will yank only from the kill-ring of main cursor. To yank from the kill-rings of every cursor use yank-rectangle, normally found at C-x r y.

Comment: Not help. In the same doc: Commands run with M-x won't be repeated for all cursors

Comment: Tried it with `emacs -q`. Works as expected. `C-SPC`, select key, `M-x mc/mark-all-like-this`, `C-g`, `C-f`, `C-SPC`, `M-f`, `M-w`, `C-g`, move to end of buffer, `M-x yank-rectangle`.

Comment: Yes, it's work. Thanks